# What exactly is a com object, and how do I use it?

Tags: c++, com

What exactly is a com object, and how do I use it?

Comment: That question is very broad, books have been written to answer that. Recommend to improve or close.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455687/what-is-com-component-object-model-in-a-nutshell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of COM is a language-neutral way of implementing objects that can be used in environments different from the one in which they were created, even across machine boundaries. For well-authored components, COM allows reuse of objects with no knowledge of their internal implementation, as it forces component implementers to provide well-defined interfaces that are separate from the implementation

More details you can check out on [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)