# What is the difference between Win32 API and COM API?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, tapi

I'm going to work on Telephony API. There exists two versions of TAPI. One is TAPI 2.x while another is TAPI 3.x. TAPI 2.x is Win32 based while TAPI 3.x is COM based. I don't know the difference between Win32 and COM APIs. So, what's the difference between these two?

Comment: [COM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/455687/11683) is a technology, Win32 API is a set of functions Windows exposes for applications to use. I doubt you should be selecting a version based on whether it's COM or not, there are more important criteria such as features and support.

Answer (score 8):

Both are part of the Windows API (sometimes called *Win32*), so the distinction is not *"Win32 vs. COM"*. It is between a C-based API comprised of a set of free functions (for TAPI 2.x) and a [COM (Component Object Model)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx) based API (for TAPI 3.x).

Many system services are exposed through COM interfaces (like the Windows Shell, or the entirety of the Windows Runtime). The decision on whether to use TAPI 3.x or 2.x is roughly outlined under [TAPI 3.x vs. TAPI 2.x](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734220.aspx).